# How to get BSD FTP and Telnet back in 10.13 (High Sierra)?

Tags: terminal, ftp, high-sierra, command-line

There are [some real problems](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35747/making-dired-work-with-ftp-on-os-x-10-13) with not having ftp and telnet present in 10.13 now as per Apple's dictate.

Has anyone found a solid way to bring BSD `ftp` and `telnet` back to macOS vs using `inetutils`?

Comment: There is Netcat available on high-sierra now.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Apple's Telnet and FTP programs are back in High Sierra thanks to this [homebrew pull request](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/19296) (by yours truly). Both the client and server of each one are back, and these are Apple's original versions of these programs.

[`inetutils` unfortunately exhibits some bugs](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-inetutils/2017-09/msg00000.html) on High Sierra so this will be a better solution and should make everyone happy.

**To install ALL the formulas in that PR, run this at the command line:**

```
brew install tnftp tnftpd telnet telnetd
```

---

Of course you can install each of these separately as well:

```
# TNFTP client & server (formerly known as LukeMFTP, presumably due to being developed by Luke Mewburn 
# and has been the default FTP for default FTP client included with NetBSD, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, DragonFly BSD, 
# Darwin (macOS), and MidnightBSD):
brew install tnftp 
brew install tnftpd 

# Telnet client & server:
brew install telnet 
brew install telnetd
```

Comment: Wow, that is some excellent work and I'm so happy to see these divided up into separate components so that we don't have to just be bound to installing all clients and services!

Comment: Everyone may also be interested to know that `tnftp` has better completion than the GNU version! This is absolutely the best solution.

Comment: How does one actually turn on the ftp server once installed with this method?

Comment: @JonThompson Should be as easy as `sudo ftpd -D`. Look in `man 8 ftpd` for more information, plus there are a lot of tutorials floating around on the net which describe this sort of thing for both BSD and Linux.

Answer (score 26):

Using Homebrew:

```
brew install inetutils
```

This will restore `telnet`, `ftp`, etc...

Can't believe Apple removed such a fundamental utilities from the command line.

Comment: Error: No available formula with the name "inetutils"

Comment: as of Oct 11, this formula is working.

Comment: To be clear, `brew install inetutils` will install GNU inetutils which will contain telnet. `brew install telnet` will install BSD telnet from macOS Sierra sources. Both will work fine.

Comment: There is a better solution now accepted as the answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312273/13220

Answer (score 18):

You could try grabbing [libtelnet](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libtelnet/libtelnet-13/) and [lukemftp](https://opensource.apple.com/source/lukemftp/lukemftp-16/) from the [open source repository](https://opensource.apple.com/release/macos-10126.html) for macOS 10.12.6 and compiling them for yourself.

If you use homebrew, BSD `telnet` is prepackaged and installable via `brew install telnet`.

Comment: There are some issues going on that this doesn't resolve as noted above unfortunately. As for the 10.12.6 source, yeah, that might be the best path at the moment, but it's not something that will likely remain a viable solution...

Comment: `brew install telnet` is the easiest solution in my opinion!

Comment: Notice the new accepted answer here @MichielB. It's the best and easiest now.

Answer (score 10):

Telnet is include in the inetutils  port in [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/). To install it use the port command:

```
sudo port install inetutils
```

Comment: The answer by @GDP2 is a better solution. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312273/13220

Comment: @yllumniate, why is it a better solution?  What if you prefer to use MacPorts?

Comment: @yllumniate this is a one-liner while the other solution requires me install an entire new framework (with a history of severe bugs). this a better solution

Comment: @GoodPerson Homebrew is never a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

grab the binaries from a Sierra install /usr/bin ;)

Comment: or a TimeMachine backup :-)

Comment: The problem is that I'm looking for a permanent solution, not a temporary patch. It's looking like we're going to have to go with FreeBSD or something else via a fork.

Comment: @ylluminate There are security reasons not to use ftp and telnet changing OS to get them sounds like the wrong solution - try using the replacement tools e.g. sftp , ssh etc

Comment: I agree with nanard copying telnet and ftp from /usr/bin on a NOT High Sierra MAC
it is fast and it works and the X-Code thing is a mess

Comment: @Mark while there are indeed reasons not to use the unsecured protocols, there are also plenty of remaining **requirements to use them** - typically when interacting with legacy systems, especially those firewalled on private networks.  Generally speaking, the decision of what protocols are allowed should be made on the *server* side, since that is the system that potentially could be compromised - forcing it on the client side is completely wrong-headed, as the designers of the client system can't know what it will be used to talk to.

Comment: @Mark I also use telnet to test open ports while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I searched through Apple support forums and found an answer that I believe will help others reinstall ftp and telnet on Mac High Sierra.

Navigate to [www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/](http://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/) Click on the HTTP download link for "Inetutils" Download "inetutils-1.9.4.tar.gz" tar zxvf inetutils-1.9.4.tar.gz

Direct ftp site -> http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/inetutils/

```
cd inetutils-1.9.4
./configure
make
sudo make install
telnet x.x.x.x port
```

I found the answer at this forum https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79056