# How can I change a scripted ftp upload to lftp for High Sierra?

Tags: macos, script, high-sierra

I am very new to coding/scripting..

I have a noob question I guess:

I have this script to upload and delete files on my remote host:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Starting Website upload ...
echo This may take some time depending on your internet connection ...
echo Waiting for remote connnection ...

/usr/bin/ftp -d server121.web-hosting.com << ftpEOF

    prompt
    cd public_html
    delete index.html
    cd images
    mdelete *.jpg
    cd ..    
    lcd /Applications/PlexEmail/streamnet/
    put index.html
    lcd images
    cd images
    mput *.jpg
    bye
ftpEOF

echo Website upload successfull ...
```

Ok so now I upgraded my mac to high sierra 10.13 and there is no ftp command anymore.

Can please someone help me out to get this to work with `lftp`?

Comment: `lftp` is not part of the standard install, what is this? And if you are open for additional software installs, why not just install `ftp` via homebrew?

Comment: Ftp isnt compiled for os high sierra via homebrew, thats why i installed lftp via homebrew, i think i is the same but it isnt:(

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299758/how-to-get-bsd-ftp-and-telnet-back-in-10-13-high-sierra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the [lftp man page](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) it seems as if `lftp` is scriptable. Something like the following should work (**untested**):

```
# upload script (save as website-update.lftp)
open server121.web-hosting.com
cd public_html
lcd /Applications/PlexEmail/streamnet/
put index.html
cd images
lcd images
mrm *.jpg
mput *.jpg
exit
```

And then use

```
lftp -f website-update.lftp
```

to execute it.

PS: `lftp` also has a `mirror` command which would this make even easier, probably.

Comment: Thank u very much patrix. I just started learning coding so sorry for that noib question:/ i will try it out. Thank you

Comment: Does it takes the username and password for the remote host from the .netric file for ftp or do i need to add something else?

Comment: @IveFlammang According to the man page it should read `.netrc`. There is no harm in trying this, actually just using `lftp server121.web-hosting.com` should get you logged in.

Comment: Thank you @patrix thats very helpfull. These days its hard to find helpfull poeple. Thanks

Comment: do you know how i can add this into a Launchagent?

Comment: @user3901913 If you have a different question, feel free to ask it using the Ask Question button at the top right. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.