# How to enable telnet server on macOS 10.13.1?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, homebrew

I wanted to add telnet server on my macbook pro(macOS 10.13.1) and followed steps in [How to get BSD FTP and Telnet back in 10.13 (High Sierra)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299758/how-to-get-bsd-ftp-and-telnet-back-in-10-13-high-sierra) to install telnetd with homebrew.

Everything was OK and I can find telnetd under /usr/local/Cellar/telnetd/54.50.1/sbin. How can I enable telnet server as Daemon?

I tried command

> sudo launchctl load -w /Users/public/telnet.plist

No error occurred but didn't work.

This telnet.plist was copied from other macbook and just modified the telnetd path. Are there other options to get `telnetd` to run and listen for incoming connections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ssh. Really - use ssh. But if you insist:

```
brew install telnetd
```

I'll leave this up since the typical homebrew services start script isn't implemented on the stable homebrew version. Once that's done, you can:

```
brew services start telnetd
```

The brew services needs a file like this in `/usr/local/Cellar/telnetd/54.50.1/homebrew.mxcl.telnetd.plist` and possibly the config file in `/usr/local/etc/telnetd.conf` or wherever.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.telnetd</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/sbin/telnetd</string>
    <string>--config</string>
    <string>/usr/local/etc/telnetd.conf</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
```

Comment: I'm too tired to put in a pull request / defect or stub the services part, but perhaps [GDP2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312273/5472) has this on their radar already. I hate to impose though since they already ported the telnetd for us all.

Comment: Thanks for making this plist. In my PR, I had Apple's original plists which facilitated management of these programs via `launchd`. I hoped that the maintainers would accept said plists to allow the daemons to be run via `brew service` but the homebrew maintainers [rejected](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/19296#discussion_r143994273) them since they needed to be installed to `/Library` or `/System` for the daemons to run properly.

Comment: Unfortunately,  homebrew seems to be more and more rejecting certain use-cases and APIs insomuch that the maintainers express a [blatant disregard](https://mikemcquaid.com/2018/03/19/open-source-maintainers-owe-you-nothing/) for users. Macports is looking like a more attractive alternative since this trend seems to be pervading homebrew in an unsettling way.

Comment: Thank you for this .plist. Could someone post what goes in `/usr/local/etc/telnetd.conf` please?

Comment: @JayKoutavas If you ask a follow on question be sure to link here or comment here. That file is optional so nothing goes in it unless you want to change some default behaviors.

Comment: I am getting an invalide .plist file on this.

Comment: @JayKoutavas Please go to [This link](https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0SP1.update/com.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities/t/telnetd.html) to get the initial `telnetd.conf`

Answer (score 2):

After installing telnetd with Homebrew, as you did, I was able to get it working with:

```
telnetd -debug [port]
```

where [port] is replaced with the number of the port on which you want to listen for incoming telnet connections.

By the way, you wrote that you located telnetd in the 'sbin' folder; you may also find a 'share' folder at the same level which contains a man page on telnetd.  According to the man page, "[t]he -debug option may be used to start up telnetd manually, instead of through inetd."

Answer (score 1):

You can install telnet through brew as well. https://brewInstall.org is a webapp to search for a mac app and get the steps to install the app.

First install `brew`using following command

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Now install telnet using following command:

```
brew install telnet
```

Now to debug connectivity to an IP (for example 34.45.123.1) on port (9200), use the following command:

```
telnet 34.45.123.1 9200
```

Comment: Note for people that are looking for the server, this answer installs the telnet client,  and not the telnet server.