# After restoring FTP server in High Sierra, how to log in to localhost?

Tags: high-sierra, ftp

I followed the instructions here https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312273/72004 to get an FTP server running on High Sierra. But when I log in to localhost, it doesn't recognize me as a user.

```
% ftp localhost
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
220 ::1 FTP server (tnftpd 20100324) ready.
Name (localhost:[my username]): [my username]
530 Login incorrect.
ftp: Login failed
```

What gives? How can I restore myself as an FTP user? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried logging in with the username `ftp` or `anonymous`? That seems to work fine for me. I haven't used `ftpd` very much, but a lot of it seems to depend on your server configuration. Some tutorials for BSD & Linux are helpful for this.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Logging in with a username of "ftp" works. But it fails with what I'm trying to do, which is to update a local WordPress installation via FTP. And maybe I should rephrase my question.

Comment: Hmm, yes, rephrasing your question would probably help so that people can get a better idea of exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem.

```
#set file ownership so we can update WP
#https://www.fetchdesigns.com/blog/failed-to-connect-to-ftp-server-localhost21-wordpress-on-mac/
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a <your username> -t user _www
sudo chown -R _www:_www <path_to_wordpress>
sudo chmod -R g+w <path_to_wordpress>

sudo chmod 777 .htaccess
sudo chmod 755 <path_to_wordpress>/wp-content/uploads
```

Hope this helps someone else.